# my donut is always a mess

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, vertices

I tried creating donuts many times but the same problem occurred every time. I don't know why it is happening. Please enlighten me with some knowledge. Please save me from this mess.
I am following blender guru's new beginner series.
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have the *Snap* and the *Proportional Editing* option activated, the second one moves all the vertices that are close to the one selected, depending on the size of the influence sphere, and the first makes the selection stick to the face you'll meet, you probably ended up with this messy result with some unwanted movements of vertices. Make sure you know how these options work and disable them as long as you don't need them:

[image]

To clean up, you can select the inner edge loops with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd>, delete them, then recreate a clean topology:

[image]

Comment: Those are both used together in that part of the tutorial to produce the icing drips as far as I can remember.

Comment: sure but I guess he must be careful about how he moves his vertices when these options are enabled, don't you think so?

Comment: proportional editing and snap-to-face are enabled to keep the icing stick to the donut and I don't understand this topology thing and kbd. I just selected outer vertices but I don't know why this happens. I am completely new to blender.

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my answer, I hope it's understandable now   ;)

Comment: @YashGoyal I suspect you had the influence set far too high when you initially enabled Proportional Editing and distorted far more of the icing mesh than you intended. You can change the circle size that appears by scrolling the mouse wheel and it can be scrolled so large that it disappears from the viewport altogether. That will distort a very large area of the mesh without moving the mouse far when you grab a vertex.  Delete the icing, separate another section from the donut and try again starting [here](https://youtu.be/7wKnPclzYY8?t=45).

Comment: @JohnEason but I reduced the influence of proportional editing

Comment: I saw that from your Blend file but it looked as if the damage had already been done! I can't see anything else that could have caused it.